# inconsistent HTML5 canvas results

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've got the following HTML5 with javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
canvas {width:200px; height:200px;
        border: solid blue 1px  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" ></canvas>
<script>
var canvas, ctx, i, tLineH = 70;

canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

for(i=0; i<50; i++){
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.moveTo(i*3+0.5, tLineH-15);
    ctx.lineTo(i*3+0.5, tLineH+15);
    ctx.stroke();
}

for(i=200; i<240; i+=4){
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.moveTo(i, tLineH-30);
    ctx.lineTo(i, tLineH-15);
    ctx.stroke();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Which produces the first image.
If I reverse the order of the *for* loops the
second image is drawn!
And if I change the height of the canvas to 300px
the third image is drawn!!

I would post the images here to show what happens but I don't have enough reputation points, so I've put them at https://www.dropbox.com/s/dun1vr4vjju3u7c/canvasTests.PNG?dl=0

I'm hoping someone can explain why the code produces the different results when it seems the drawings should be identical.

Thanks,
Gerard

Comment: This is because order of drawings do matter on canvas :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the width and height of the canvas using css.
In the javascript, set it with:

```
ctx.canvas.height = 200;
ctx.canvas.width = 200;
```

Setting the value with css will stretch out the canvas, while setting it with javascript resizes it.

Comment: Thanks very much, that's good to know.  Why do you think the order of the two for loops changes the resulting drawing?

Comment: try using beginPath and closePath. That might play a factor.

Comment: you call beginPath() before you draw a line, and you call closePath() after you are finished drawing a line.